# .gitignore doesn't ignores directories

Tags: gitignore

I've got this .gitignore file:

```
[admin]/
[editor]/
[gamemodes]/
[gameplay]/
[managers]/
[web]/
```

But the `git status` shows that:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        [admin]/
        [editor]/
        [gamemodes]/
        [gameplay]/
        [managers]/
        [web]/
        editor_dump/
        editor_map_backups/
        editor_test/
        guieditor/
```

Why is it happening? Of course, I've got .gitignore in the right place.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to just add the .gitignore to the repo. Try to do that first if you didn't do that!

Comment: Nope, it's not the problem, the .gitignore file is in the repository. Even if it wasn't, the files should be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me if I escape the brackets.

```
ls -a
```

> .      ..      .git        .gitignore  [admin]

```
more .gitignore
```

> \[admin\]

```
 git status
```

> On branch master
>
> Initial commit
>
> Untracked files:
>    (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
>
> .gitignore

The brackets are used to specify a range of characters. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

So if they're not escaped then you are essentially trying to match any one character a, d, m, i, n.

Comment: In `less .gitignore`: `[admin]`, in `git status`: Untracked files: [admin]/

Comment: Thanks for resolving this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this:

```
# ignore everything
*

# but not fp_ scripts
!fp_*

# ...and other
!.gitignore
!README.md
```

Now it's working fine. Still idk why older `.gitignore` doesn't worked.

Comment: Did you see my answer? You can use [] to specify different characters or a range of characters.